# checkbox selected true by using condition

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular
this is my data

```
$scope.checkgoogleKeywordIdsData=[
{"AdGroupId":"37446130209","Id":"41941982"},
{"AdGroupId":"34657098157","Id":"1275289507"},
{"AdGroupId":"37446130209","Id":"41941972"}
];
```

I want ng-checked="true"  if '$scope.checkgoogleKeywordIdsData' have  'AdGroupId' and 'Id'

```
<input type="checkbox"  
 ng-checked="checkgoogleKeywordIdsData.indexOf({ 'AdGroupId':'34657098157', 'Id': '1275289507' })>-1" />
```

I am sorry for my English

thank you helping me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for will do, check below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/mn83go5m/2/

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="haveIds()" /> 

$scope.haveIds = function(){
  var value = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.checkgoogleKeywordIdsData.length; i++) {
    if($scope.checkgoogleKeywordIdsData[i].AdGroupId != null && $scope.checkgoogleKeywordIdsData[i].Id != null){
        value = true;
    }
  }  
  return value;
}
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: thanks for giving replay, Can we give  ng-checked condition in html page

Comment: Only in the html would make the html dirty with too much js code, the best practice is to do the logic in the controller like I did...

Comment: my checkbox in ui-grid there is so many conditions are there like 

I am pushing colimns in coldefs,In there one check have these conditions,In there this condition is not working, For Ex:
ng-checked="grid.appScope.checkIdsSelectedData.indexOf(row.entity.CampaignId) > -1||grid.appScope.checkIdsSelectedData.indexOf(row.entity.AdGroupId) > -1||bmt_.where(grid.appScope.checkgoogleKeywordIdsData, {\'AdGroupId\':row.entity.AdGroupId, \'Id\': row.entity.Id}).length>0"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of condition use indexOf() function.

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-checked="checkgoogleKeywordIdsData.indexOf({'AdGroupId':'37446130209','Id':'41941982'})"/>
```